# Textwatcher with Livedata

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher, android-livedata

I'm building an Android app this is my Fragment

```
 public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, mViewModelFactory).get(ListMedicosViewModel.class);
    setupView();
    setProgress(true);
    mViewModel.loadMedicos();
    mViewModel.getApiResponse().observe(this, apiResponse -> {
        if (apiResponse.getError() != null) {
            handleError(apiResponse.getError());
        } else {
            handleResponse(apiResponse.getMedicos());
        }
    });
```

and this is mi ViewModel:

```
public class ListMedicosViewModel extends ViewModel {

private MediatorLiveData<ApiResponseMedicos> mApiMedicosResponse;
private SaludRepository mSaludRepository;
@Inject
public ListMedicosViewModel(SaludRepository saludRepository) {
    mApiMedicosResponse = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    mSaludRepository = saludRepository;
}
@NonNull
public LiveData<ApiResponseMedicos> getApiResponse() {
    return mApiMedicosResponse;
}
public LiveData<ApiResponseMedicos> loadMedicos() {
    mApiMedicosResponse.addSource(
            mSaludRepository.getMedicos(),
            apiResponse -> mApiMedicosResponse.setValue(apiResponse)
    );
    return mApiMedicosResponse;
}
```

}

I would like to add an EditText to filter my RecyclerView, but I dont know How to do it.

Comment: where is the RecyclerView to filter into? and how are you using a View class to filter it? do you mean you would like to display the filtered responses in an EditText on a RecyclerView?

Comment: Inside the RecyclerView  there is a list of "medicos" I want to filter the list by this EditText  all those "medicos" by name.